# Showing response from restful service after CRUD operations in ExtJS grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am performing CRUD operations on my grid using API. Everything is working fine but my requirement is to show the response that is returned from my restful WCF service. For example, if I delete a record I am returning "Record deleted" as response. I want to show this same response to the user. The code for my store is as follows:

```
Ext.define('DHT.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'DHT.model.User',
    pageSize: 5,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        timeout: 120000,
        noCache: false,
        api: {
            read: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/GetAlbum',
            create: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/AddAlbum',
            update: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/UpdateAlbum',
            destroy: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/DeleteRecord'
        },

        reader:
        {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'GetAlbumResult[0].AlbumList',
            totalProperty: 'GetAlbumResult[0].results',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },

        writer:
        {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});
```

Can someone please point out where am I supposed to add the functionality or provide any sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you reload your store after each operation? If so, add a listener to your store and show a message box when the operation is finished:

```
Ext.define('DHT.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    [...]
    listeners:
    {
        load: function(store, records, success)
        {
            Ext.Msg.alert('title','message');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I do not load store after every operation. For delete I use: grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex); For insert I use: this.getUsersStore().add(values); For updating I am using edit plugin. All these operations are done in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in your store datachanged or update events

```
Ext.define('DHT.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    [...]
    listeners:
    {
        datachanged: function( cmp, eOpts )
        {
            //Do what you want here
        },
        update: function( cmp, record, operation, modifiedFieldNames, eOpts )
        {
            //Check what the operation is of type and display the message accordingly
            //Ext.data.Model.EDIT
            //Ext.data.Model.REJECT
            //Ext.data.Model.COMMIT
        }
    }
   }
```